# jQuery radiobutton not checked selector

Tags: jquery, css

I have the follow selector that I would like to target unchecked radiobuttons that are immediate descendents of the .noRadioButton class.

```
$('.noRadioButton > input:radio:not(:checked)').click(DialogOpen);
```

When my page loads with a radio button checked, I expect my selector to work when I uncheck it then recheck it. Any suggestions on why this isn't the case?

Answer (score 1):

You should use event delegation in that case:

```
$('.noRadioButton ').on('click','> input:radio:not(:checked)',DialogOpen);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working as expected.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adrfkmau/
My selector only works when the page loads wiith the No radio unchecked.